# Open a link and active a checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label

Im trying to create an element, which when clicked, both opens a hyperlink and actives a label connected to a checkbox. The element is a menu item. When that menu item is clicked, I want the anchor/link to be opened and the menu to be closed through CSS, hence the checkbox.

However, whenever I put the label inside the hyperlink, the checkbox gets checked, but the hyperlink does not get opened.

```
<a href="#anchor">
    <label for="checkbox">
        Menu Item
    </label>
</a>
```

When I put the hyperlink inside the label, the opposite happens: the link gets opened, but the checkbox does not get checked.

```
<label for="checkbox">
    <a href="#anchor">
        Menu Item
    </a>
</label>
```

Is it possible to active the label and open the hyperlink simultaneously without using JavaScript? If so, how?

Comment: can you show your full html as `#anchor`...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `a` element! It's not valid to have a label inside an anchor or an anchor inside a label.

Just add the `onclick="location.hash=''"` event for your `input` element to run code. *(an example below)*

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="location.hash='#anchor';" />
<label for="checkbox">Menu Item</label>
<!-- div for margin -->
<div style="height:10000px"></div>
<a name="anchor">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>
```